# How to add custom image to a UITableviewController in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I am new to Xcode, and I am currently building my first app.  I've searched long and hard to try and find the proper tutorial but I can't find one.  I am looking for a way to be able to insert a custom background in my UITableViewController.  I can change the color, but that is it.  What I am looking to do is set my PNG image behind the static cells I've created, and drop the opacity on those cells so the custom image comes through.  Can someone please give me a way to do this either through the IB (storyboard) or through the coding. Much appreciated!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out this question and the answer marked as correct. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1637871/1354251 The steps listed say to create a UIViewController and then create your TableView programmatically on top of the background image.

Comment: @Kyle that's quite an old question, i think it is better to use setBackgroundView method now

Answer (score 2):

I think the easier and correct way is to:

```
[tableView setBackgroundView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"]]];
```

You can include this code in viewDidLoad to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

for cell's background :, do this in `willDisplayCell:atIndexPath:` method

```
 UIImageView *cellImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImageimageNamed:@"image.png"]]];
CGRect Frame = cell.backgroundView.bounds;
cellImageView.frame = newFrame;

[cell.backgroundView addSubview:cellImageView];
```

for tableview background , do this in `viewDidLoad:` method

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackgroundPattern.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  UIImageView *ivwCellBackground=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
   [ivwCellBackground setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:CELL_BACKGROUNGIMAGE]];
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    [cell setBackgroundView:ivwCellBackground];    

    [ivwCellBackground release];
    ivwCellBackground=nil;
```